# Cannot read property 'getTime' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting this error while trying to set up a counter which calculates the total time taken to fill a particular form .Have tried the following things,

```
//script


var timeStart;
var timeStop;

$(document).load(function() {
    timeStart = new Date();
});

$('#form_3').on('submit', function() {
    timeStop = Math.round((timeStart.getTime() - new Date().getTime()) / 1000);
    console.debug('time taken from load till submit: ' + timeStop);
});
```

//script

now getting error uncaught TypeError:Cannot read property 'getTime' of undefined.

Comment: `(new Date()).getTime()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be you can try `(new Date()).getTime())`:

```
timeStop = Math.round((timeStart.getTime() - (new Date()).getTime()) / 1000);
```

Comment: @Nishanthi.it worked...but I am not getting the desired output.it is always coming -1.

Comment: Try this: timeStop = Math.round(((new Date()).getTime() - timeStart.getTime())   / 1000);

Comment: You should use Time = EndTime - StartTime. But in the code, you are trying to use Time = StartTime - EndTime. That is why it is coming in negative.

Comment: @Nishanthi...still coming one.

Comment: Try console.log (timeStart.getTime()); console.log ((new Date()).getTime()); and check what is the actual difference. I have checked and its coming perfectly for me.